# Minimizing browser window in Firefox & Chrome adds white space to right of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

As the title suggests, when I resize my Chrome or Firefox browser window, little by little, white space is added to the right side of the page. I fixed this by setting `width:100%`to `navbar-header`(refer to code below), but now it's caused another problem. I'm not sure if it's possible to cater for both, but I need it to.

It's a bit hard to explain what's happened, so hopefully the two images below will be enough explanation.

[image]

The above image is how my website looks after setting `width:100%`to `navbar-header`. Below is how I want it to look.

[image]

So, does anyone know how I can solve this issue? The CSS and HTML is below.

```css
html {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
}

body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
}

p {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 color:#1C1C1C;
}

img {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

.maincontainer {
 position:relative;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}

.container {
 width:100%;
 min-height:100%;
 position:relative;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

.container:after {
 content:"";
 display:block;
}

.logo {
 float:left;
 margin-left:20px;
 font-family:'Advent Pro', sans-serif;
 font-weight:100;
 color:#1C1C1C;
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
 .logo {
  float:left;
  margin-left:5px;
  font-family:'Advent Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight:100;
  color:#1C1C1C;
 }
}

.name {
 float:left;
 margin:5px 10px 0px 10px;
 font-size:37px;
}

.type {
 float:left;
 width:50px;
 margin-top:6px;
 padding:1px 0px 1px 10px;
 font-size:15px;
 border-left:1px solid #1C1C1C;
}

.nav {
 float:right;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 list-style:none;
 width:300px;
}

@media screen and (min-width:500px) {
 .nav {
  float:right;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  width:444px;
 }
}

.nav li {
 float:left;
 padding:16px 10px 13px 10px;
 font-family:'Advent Pro', sans-serif;
 font-weight:200;
 font-size:17px;
 color:#1C1C1C;
}

@media screen and (min-width:500px) {
 .nav li {
  float:left;
  padding:16px 25px 13px 25px;
  font-family:'Advent Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight:200;
  font-size:17px;
  color:#1C1C1C;
 }
}

.reposition {
 position:absolute;
 left:50%;
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -0%);
 -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -0%);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
 .reposition {
  position:static;
  float:right;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-0%, -0%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-0%, -0%);
 }
}

.nav li:hover {
 border-bottom:2px solid #1C1C1C;
}

.navbar-toggle {
 margin-top:13px;
 margin-right:-5px;
}

.collapse {
 height:56px;
}

.navbar-header {
 height:55px;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

 <head>
  
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     
     <title>Tim Corin Photography</title>
     
     <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One|Josefin+Slab|Cinzel|Jura:400,300|Nixie+One|Advent+Pro:100,300,200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
     <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
     
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>

 </head>
   
 <body onLoad="switchImage('slideImg')">
   
 <div class="maincontainer">
 
 <div class="mainheader">

   <div class="navbar navbar-default">
       
    <div class="container">
       
        <div class="navbar-header">
       
     <a href="index.html">
   
      <div class="logo">
   
       <p class="name">Tim Corin</p>
  
       <p class="type">Wildlife Photography</p>
    
      </div>
   
     </a>
            
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
         
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          
         </button>
        
        </div>
        
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
     
         <div class="reposition">
         
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         
          <a href=""><li class="home">Home</li></a>
      <a href=""><li class="gallery">Gallery</li></a>
      <a href=""><li>About</li></a>
      <a href=""><li>Contact</li></a>
      <a href=""><li>Blog</li></a>
      
         </ul>
         
         </div>
        
        </div>
       
       </div>
       
   </div>
   
  </div>
   
  </div>
 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
   
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
   </body>
   
</html>
```

Comment: Remove width 100%, give float: left and display: inline-block to .navbar-header !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can float the two divs.  Remove the `width: 100%` on the `.navbar-header` css first, then:

```
.navbar-header {
  float: left;
}

.navbar-collapse {
  float: right;
}
```

Hope this helps.  Best.

Comment: Thank you @R.A. Lucas. It worked. But now it has cause another problem; navbar-toggle (the "button" that appears when the browser is resized smaller than 768px) is covering my logo...

Comment: any ideas? I just discovered as well, that even though it has fixed it in FF and Chrome, now it is gone odd in Safari :(.

Comment: Don't worry, I fixed it, yay!

Answer (score 0):

Before the navbar-header and navebar-collapse i am adding two div name as separate. It's the parent group of navbar-header and navebar-collapse.

And i'll give the following CSS and HTML:

```
.separate
        {
        Float: left;
        width:50%;
        }


<div class="navbar navbar-default">

            <div class="container">
            <div class="separate">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                   .......
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="separate">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <div class="reposition">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" ...
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Tim Corin Photography</title>

        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One|Josefin+Slab|Cinzel|Jura:400,300|Nixie+One|Advent+Pro:100,300,200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body onLoad="switchImage('slideImg')">

    <div class="maincontainer">

    <div class="mainheader">

        <div class="navbar navbar-default">

            <div class="container">

                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <a href="index.html">

                        <div class="logo">

                            <p class="name">Tim Corin</p>

                            <p class="type">Wildlife Photography</p>

                        </div>

                    </a>

                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">

                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>

                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                    </button>
                    <div class="reposition">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                        <a href=""><li class="home">Home</li></a>
                        <a href=""><li class="gallery">Gallery</li></a>
                        <a href=""><li>About</li></a>
                        <a href=""><li>Contact</li></a>
                        <a href=""><li>Blog</li></a>

                    </ul>

                    </div>

</div>

                </div>



            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>

    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```